# PySimpleGUI - refreshing window

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm having trouble refreshing a PySimpleGUI window. I get people from my db, then display a window giving info about a single person. The 'Next' button can then be pressed which will show details of the next person. This code works but opens a new window for each person (rather than refreshing the current window).

```
people = conn.execute('''SELECT * FROM people''')

people_tuple = people.fetchall()

for index, person in enumerate(people_tuple):
    frame_1 = [
        # name
        [sg.Text(people_tuple[index][1] + " " + people_tuple[index][2], key='name')],
    ]

    frame_2 = [
        # .......
    ]

    layout = [
        # row 1
        [sg.Frame('Person', frame_1, pad=(0, 5)), sg.Frame('Contact Details', frame_2, pad=(0, (14, 5)), key='Hide')],
        [sg.Button('Next')],
    ]

    window = sg.Window('Window', layout, finalize=True)

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()

        # window closed
        if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
            sys.exit()

        # create_event button pressed
        elif event == 'Event':
            # .......

    window.close()
```

This code doesn't refresh the window at all.

```
layout = [
    [sg.Button('Next')],
]

window = sg.Window('Window', layout, finalize=True)

people = conn.execute('''SELECT * FROM people''')

people_tuple = people.fetchall()

for index, person in enumerate(people_tuple):
    frame_1 = [
        # name
        [sg.Text(people_tuple[index][1] + " " + people_tuple[index][2], key='name')],
    ]

    frame_2 = [
        # .......
    ]

    layout = [
        # row 1
        [sg.Frame('Person', frame_1, pad=(0, 5)), sg.Frame('Contact Details', frame_2, pad=(0, (14, 5)), key='Hide')],
        [sg.Button('Next')],
    ]

    window.refresh()

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()

        # window closed
        if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
            sys.exit()

        # create_event button pressed
        elif event == 'Event':
            # .......

    window.refresh()
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Each window created and closed in your `for` loop, that's why it opens a new window for each person, rather than refreshing the current window.

Should create a window, then loop each person to update elements in that window.

Example code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def refresh(index):
    person = people_tuple[index]
    window['No.'].update(str(index+1))
    for i, key in enumerate(('Region', 'Name', 'Phone', 'States')):
        window[key].update(person[i])

"""
people = conn.execute('''SELECT * FROM people''')
people_tuple = people.fetchall()
"""
# Fake data
people_tuple = (
    ('New England', 'Paul Hughes', '617-283-6142', 'Connecticut, Maine, Massachusetts, New Hampshire, Rhode Island, Vermont'),
    ('Northeast and Caribbean', 'Deborah Croft', '347-417-4339', 'New Jersey, New York, Commonwealth of Puerto Rico, U.S. Virgin Islands'),
    ('Mid-Atlantic', 'William Powell', '215-629-6735', 'Delaware, Maryland, Pennsylvania, Virginia, West Virginia, portions of New Jersey, Europe, Africa, Middle East'),
    ('Southeast Sunbelt', 'Cathleen Rineer-Garber', '404-314-8540', 'Alabama, Florida, Georgia, Kentucky, Mississippi, North Carolina, South Carolina, Tennessee'),
    ('Great Lakes', 'Tanya Schusler', '847-909-1682', 'Illinois, Indiana, Michigan, Minnesota, Ohio, Wisconsin'),
)
records = len(people_tuple)
if records == 0:
    quit()

font = ('Courier New', 16)
sg.theme('DarkBlue4')
sg.set_options(font=font)


left = [
    [sg.Text('Record:'), sg.Text('', expand_x=True, key='No.' )],
    [sg.Text('Name  :'), sg.Text('', expand_x=True, key='Name')],
]
right = [
    [sg.Text('Region:'), sg.Text('', expand_x=True, key='Region')],
    [sg.Text('Phone :'), sg.Text('', expand_x=True, key='Phone' )],
    [sg.Text('States:', size=(7, 3)), sg.Text('', size=(40, 3),  key='States')],
]
layout = [
    [sg.Frame('Person', left, expand_x=True)],
    [sg.Frame('Contact', right)],
    [sg.Button('PREV'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('NEXT')],
]
window = sg.Window('Contact Information', layout, finalize=True)
index = 0
refresh(index)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event in ('PREV', 'NEXT'):
        diff = -1 if event == 'PREV' else +1
        index = (index + diff) % records
        refresh(index)

window.close()
```

[image]